# Java filtering the object list to string array with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class like this

```
public class Host {

  private HTMLToken.TokenType type;
  private StringBuilder content;

  public Host(HTMLToken.TokenType type) {
    this.type = type;
    content = new StringBuilder();
  }


  String contentAsString() {
    return content.toString();
  }

  void addStrig(String x) {
    content.append(x);
  }

  public enum TokenType {
    TAG, TEXT
  }

}
```

and static function like this

```
 public static String[] filterLength(List<Host> hostList, int length) {
    return hostList.stream().filter(str -> str.contentAsString().length() > length)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
  }
```

The problem is inside of filterLength function I can't return stream as a String array(I want to return content in the Host class) because List holds Host object how can I return as a string in 1 line code?

Comment: Which string result do you want? The result of `contentAsString()`? Then why not map *before* filtering? `return hostList.stream() .map(Host::contentAsString) .filter(str -> str.length() > length) .toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Transform each object in stream

You are successfully streaming, filtering, and collecting a bunch of `Host` objects into an array. But you seem to be asking how to instead collect a *string representation* of each `Host` object.

So, you need to add a step to your streaming operations. For each `Host` object, we want to generate and collect a `String` object.

### `Stream#map`

To transform from the objects being streamed to a different kind of object, use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)).

Here is an analog of your code, using [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). We transform each filtered `LocalDate` object to a `String` object by passing a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html): `LocalDate :: toString`.

```java
List < LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( 4 ) ;
dates.add( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY, 11 ) ) ;
dates.add( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY, 12 ) ) ;
dates.add( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY, 13 ) ) ;
dates.add( LocalDate.of( 2022 , Month.JANUARY, 14 ) ) ;

String[] results = 
    dates
    .stream()
    .filter( localDate -> localDate.getDayOfMonth() > 12 )
    .map( LocalDate :: toString )  //  
    .toArray( String[] :: new ) ;

System.out.println( "results = " + String.join( ", " , results ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/BZFTkT).

> results = 2022-01-13, 2022-01-14

I see you have a `contentAsString` method. I will guess that method returns the kind of text you want to collect.

So your code should be something like the following, passing method reference `Host :: contentAsString` to `Stream#map`.

```java
return 
    hostList
    .stream()
    .filter( str -> str.contentAsString().length() > length )
    .map( host -> Host::contentAsString )  //  Add this step.
    .toArray( String[]::new );
```

That code is effective but inefficient. No need to execute `contentAsString` method twice per input. We can fix this by putting the `map` call first, then filter based on the length of the already-produced string.

```java
return 
    hostList
    .stream()
    .map( host -> Host::contentAsString )  //  Add this step.
    .filter( string -> string.length() > length )  //  Change this step.
    .toArray( String[]::new );
```